# Using Angular With Magento (conflict with prototype.js?)

Tags: angularjs, magento, prototypejs

I need to use Angular.js on a Magento product page but I'm stuck very quickly, as soon as I declare my app, it generates this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' of null
at $$SanitizeUriProvider (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:18134:35)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/js/prototype/prototype.js:391:23)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:4733:14)
at provider (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:4547:36)
at http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:365:32
at forEach (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:335:20)
at Object.provider (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:4537:9)
at ngModule (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:2569:16)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:4718:19)
at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost/js/angular/angular.js:4611:35)
```

I obviously suspect a conflict between prototype.js and angular but couldn't find any solution so far.

The different JS files are loaded in this order:
1/ jQuery
2/ Prototype
3/ Angular

Anybody has any hint? Or is it simply impossible to achieve?
Thanks!

EDIT: So in case somebody is interested:
- Magento 1.9.2.4 (thus prototype.js 1.7) doesn't get along with Angular 1.5.8
- I used Angular 1.4.3 and it worked fine
- I'm stopping here then
What significant do I loose of using Angular 1.4 instead of 1.5?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to use one-way bindings (included in Angular 1.5) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-

The only solution I found was to use Angular 1.4.